# Saving CLLocation to CoreData While app is in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, cllocationmanager

I've found multiple similiraties with other question but I really don't find any useful answer to my question.
My Sport-Tracker iOS application will trace the positions even in background. Every 50 locations, I will save the array of `CLLocation` to a `CoreData`'s SportActivity. But if My application is in background while saving with the code:

```
NSError *error;
if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error])
    NSLog(@"Error saving data: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
```

My `_managedObjectContext` is referenced like this:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
 if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
    return _managedObjectContext;
 }
 NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
 if (coordinator != nil) {
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
 }
 return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

I can see on log this error:

```
Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier a3,
or it may have already been ended.
Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
```

To save data on my application, I add on

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

Location(My `CoreData`'s object containig coordinates) to an `NSMutableArray`. When Array count 50 elements, I call the save instance of `CoreData`

```
for (CLLocation *location in _locations) {
    Location *locationObject = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] newLocationForActivity:_currentActivity];

    locationObject.timestamp = [NSDate new];
    locationObject.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude;
    locationObject.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;
    locationObject.altitude = location.altitude;
    [locationArray addObject:locationObject];
}
```

Comment: when in background you code is running?

Comment: Can you show how you call the save code from `didUpdateLocations`?  Do you start a background task to save the data?

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, I've added some information about my code.

Comment: Are you using `beginBackgroundTask` and `endBackgroundTask`? Your error message makes it sound like you do, but you didn't mention it.

Comment: @fustalol can you please show the code where you save the core data once the array has 50 items and how you call that code?  Also, why do you wait until the array has 50 items? Saving a core data entity is a trivial amount of work and you can easily save each one as you go and you won't risk data loss if your app is terminated.